# Managing LetsEncrypt Certificate expiration and auto-renewals

Tags: windows, powershell, ssl, certificate, letsencrypt

I've been experimenting with LetsEncrypt SSL certificates and managed to get certificates set up and installed on Windows for use with IIS using the [ACMESharp Powershell library](https://github.com/ebekker/ACMESharp). The process to do this is reasonably straight forward and the cert works fine.

But... certificates have a relatively short lifetime of 3 months and since the process is now self-managed - as opposed to some vendor reminding you to renew - I'm worried about notifications of when renewals are required.

Can somebody recommend a good way to check for expired certificates and then - at minimum - send out some sort of notification, or even better to automatically renew the certificate?

Comment: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/expiration-emails-too-many-unnecessary-etc/9502

Comment: Thanks Eric - that's useful to at least get notified, but every 3 months is a bit much to have to attend to this. Still looking for idea for an automated solution (hopefully without scheduled tasks).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm posting an answer to my own question and link to a blog post to lay out the solution that worked for me, even though the original answer came from @dustinmoris's comment who pointed me at the **letsencrypt-win-simple** auto-renew feature (which I missed initially).

Using **[letsencrypt-win-simple](https://github.com/Lone-Coder/letsencrypt-win-simple)** you can use the `--renew` switch to automatically renew all previously registered domains or you can specify a specific domain.

```
# renew all domains that need it 
letsencrypt --renew

#renew specific domain if required
letsencrypt --renew --manualhost mysite.com
```

This will renew the domain if it's expired or close to it. This tool also installs a scheduled task that runs daily to run the renew cycle and attempts to renew all certificates that need it.

I ended up [writing a detailed blog post](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Feb/22/Using-Lets-Encrypt-with-IIS-on-Windows) that goes through the features of the current functionality of **letsencrypt-win-simple**, **ACMESharp** and **Certify**.

Comment: The standard today is https://github.com/sjkp/letsencrypt-siteextension. I also wrote a WebJob on top of it with some features such as multi Web App support and less dependencies and potential points of failure: https://github.com/ohadschn/letsencrypt-webapp-renewer/

Answer (score 3):

LetsEncrypt supports [auto renewal](https://letsencrypt.org/howitworks/#writing-your-own-renewal-script) out of the box. An example how this is done with a Windows Azure Web Role can be found here: https://github.com/sjkp/letsencrypt-siteextension

If you are hosting in Windows Azure you can install this site extension and don't need to do it yourself. This is a good [guide on how to set it up](https://gooroo.io/GoorooTHINK/Article/16420/Lets-Encrypt-Azure-Web-Apps-the-Free-and-Easy-Way/20073#.VspId5yLSUU).

Support for LetsEncrypt was one of the [hottest feature requests](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/6737285-add-support-for-free-ssl-certs-like-those-from-let) for Azure websites and Microsoft has marked it as community resolved after reviewing the above extension, so definitely worth a look!

Comment: Yeah I saw Nik's post, but it talks about Azure. I'm looking for a solution to get the raw cert so I can install it into IIS. There's a ton of cruft that has to do with Azure that I have no need for as it just talks about the Azure extension.

Comment: I assume you saw [letsencrypt-win-simple](https://github.com/sjkp/letsencrypt-win-simple) as well. I have to admit that I haven't used this project myself yet, but it says that it has auto renewal working with a windows task schedule. From your above comment I can see you are looking for a solution without a scheduled task. What were you thinking of more specifically?